# Babelify "let" to "var"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, babeljs

I am running babel in grunt.
And I used to used `presets: ['env']` but that added an underscore in front of my services in angular.

Example

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['me', 'threads', function (_me, _threads) {

var ctrl= this;
msgCtrl.me = _me;
msgCtrl.threads = _threads;

...
```

Because of that it couldn't find the service and it all crashed, so if anyone know how to remove the underscore that would be the best.

But now I am using plugins like this

```
plugins: [
                'transform-es2015-arrow-functions',
                'transform-es2015-destructuring',
                'transform-es2015-shorthand-properties',
                'transform-es2015-template-literals',
                'check-es2015-constants',
                'transform-es2015-spread',
                'angularjs-annotate'
            ]
```

And that works fine, except I can't find a preset that converts `let`to `var`

So does anyone know how to either stop babel from adding `_` to mt services, or a plugin that converts `let` to `var`?

Thank you

Comment: What was the original code that produced that?

Comment: If using `env` before was fine, why stop using it when you use `angularjs-annotate`?

Comment: `env` was fine regardint `let` but it added underscores

Comment: Why would those underscores make any difference? The array string values should still resolve the proper services into the variables, regardless of how they're named, unless you're doing something really strange and unorthodox.

Comment: Adding the underscores is expected behavior in some cases in Babel, you can't avoid it. The whole point of `angularjs-annotate` is to allow Angular to still work given that renaming. But you also already use the array-form of the controller, so it double-shouldn't-matter.

Comment: Would using [the `$inject` notation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#-inject-property-annotation) fix this, or does it still have the same problem?

Comment: Also, using [the `ng-strict-di` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#using-strict-dependency-injection) might help you identify any controllers that have accidentally used the implicit annotations, since it appears that is the mistake.